# Gradle sync and proxy error in Android Studio 1.3.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have started praticing android using udacity tutorials. i am suppose to import existing project into Android studio.My internet connection uses proxy server to connect to rest of world. I have imported an external project and i set proxy settings in

**File--> Appearance and Behavior--> System Settings -->Http.**
while importing external project it gives following error:-

> 2:59:20 PM Gradle sync started 12:59:33 PM Gradle sync failed: Unknown
>   host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings
>   in Gradle.
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

i have tried setting proxy in 
**gradle.properties** as shown [**here**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

and i have also read other similar questions in stack overflow and treid to troubleshoot but nothing works..!!

**One strange thing i noticed is that this issue persist with imported files. when i create any new project on studio. it gets open instantly without errors**

**The project i am importing can be downloaded from** [**here**](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2)

please Help

Answer (score 7):

**In Android studio 1.3 & Above**

Configuring HTTP proxy for downloading dependencies is done via standard JVM system properties. In default HTTP proxy configured in gradle.properties file but we have to configure separate settings for **HTTPS proxy** too.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.1.1  //Your Proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080         //Your Port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.1.1   //HTTPS Proxy Configuration
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080         //HTTPS Proxy Configuration
```

Comment: I do not use proxy. how can I know the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the proxy info alone didn't help me (it was actually already there in mine), but adding the user and password worked for me, even though my proxy doesn't require it.

Add this to the bottom of your **gradle.properties** file and leave the following just like this if your proxy doesn't require authentication:

```
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

Answer (score 0):

at my case, the problem is the internet connection. Unstable connection cause this error.

Sometime this popup appears (but for android studio), you must check it to allow access.

[image: allow access]